# Can I ask this question in Music Fans SE?

Tags: discussion

I like to know the name of a non singer girl dancer in a music video. Is Music fans SE a place to ask such question? If not, can you recommend a SE to ask that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely NOT on Music Fans. If anywhere, then probably [Movies & Television](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: So, identifying Jerome (from Moriss Day and the Time) or Bobby Farrell (from Boney M) wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: Actually, that WOULD be allowed, because they are the musicians. Though most such identifications would be pretty routine and wouldn't really make good questions. Asking about the non-musicians in a music video isn't really a music question.

Comment: Jerome and Bobby Farrell are not musicians but dancers. How do we know if the person is just an extra, a dancer considered as a band member or a musician of the band? It seems that for you, the question is allowed only if we know the answer, but how could we know the answer if the question is not asked?

Comment: It is interesting about Bobby Farrell, that he did not perform on the studio recording, only in the live performances - such a thing never occurred to me. I'm going to vote for your answer as the most balanced and appropriate of the three answers.

Comment: This question would most like *not* be appropriate on [movies.se].

Answer (score 4):

Although this is a bit on the periphery of what we cover, I would personally consider it a legitimate question for this site.  I'm not sure who would be likely to know more about music videos than music fans, and dance and music frequently go together.

Also, as a side note, we need questions far more than Movies & Television does.

Comment: It's cool that you think so ,  but i can't really go against what a mod says

Comment: Meta is a place for the community as a whole to hash out things like what is and isn't on topic.  SE is managed by the moderators, not controlled by them.  If Meta.MusicFans was more active, we might get a pattern of votes on the two alternatives that would demonstrate the will of the larger community.  As it is, maybe we'll at least get some minimal debate on the topic.

Comment: Don't worry, the question wouldn't be appropriate on [movies.se] anyway. They don't need these questions either.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can find a lots of bands that have famous frontmen or dancers that stay with the band over years.

A few examples :

- Katrin Quinol in the band Black Box (essentially lip syncing for music videos, album cover art).
- Jerome Benton in the band Morris Day and the Time (dancing, interactions with Morris on live events)
- Bobby Farrell, lead frontman of Boney M.

Lots of 90's Eurodance producers used frontman models or dancers to promote their work.

I understand it would be not in the scope to identify a one-time dancer in the background of a local TV performance. But as I said earlier, some particular cases of a dancer that have a specific role in the band would be allowed.